# Find AND RETURN an object from a List or ArrayList that matches given criteria

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a list of objects (tasks) and I'd like to find **and return** the task that matches a given id if it exists. The ids are string in this case.

I know I could just loop through the list items, but I want to know if there's a more efficient way of accomplishing this because I'm using this inside another loop.

I've read about overriding the equals method in the Task class, but that's only useful for finding out if the task is there, I'd like to return it too so I can edit it. I haven't found anything that actually returns the object.

I haven't written any code for what I'm asking, but here's the code I want to insert it into:

```
    List<Task> serverTasks;
    List<LocalTask> localTasks;
    Task currentTask;
    LocalTask currentLocalTask;

    // Loop through list of lists
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {

        //Get server tasks and local tasks from list
        serverTasks = mService.tasks().list(lists.get(i).getId()).execute().getItems();
        localTasks = mPresenter.getTasksFromList(lists.get(i).getId());

        if (serverTasks != null && !serverTasks.isEmpty()) {
            currentTask = serverTasks.get(i);

            //check if server task exists in local task list
            if (mPresenter.taskExistsInDB(currentTask.getId())) {
                //here I'd like to get the local task from the local task list 
                // based on the server task Id (which is the same)
                //WITHOUT making a database query or looping through the local task list

            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post some code, maybe you could use a map (id as key) but that's hard to say without seeing some code

Comment: @RC I've updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: @RC Come to think of it, I'm already querying the database when I call mPresenter.taskExistsInDB. I might as well return it in that same method right?  But i'd be making a bunch of calls to the database, which doesn't seem right. If I can find a way of finding a task in a list of objects based on the object's ID, I could avoid querying the database multiple times. Only once to save the list of local Tasks.